# uitableview - custom images keep loading in cell.contentView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I am adding a `UIImageView` to `cell.contentView`. The problem is that when the cell scrolls off the screen and back on, it adds the same image again on top of the one that is already there. This happens continuously until I get a very stacked-up blurry image.

Do you have to keep removing any image views that you add to `cell.contentView`? If so, in what delegate method do you do that in?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]];

    imageView.center = CGPointMake(310, 48);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without any code to see what's going on, but it sounds like your problem is probably related to table cell reuse, which is a recommended practice and is usually implemented by the XCode template. Can you post some of your code?

Comment: just out of curiosity, if you're loading the cell from a nib, why don't you add the image in the nib instead of doing it programmatically?

Comment: the image is dynamic and loaded from a server so I can't put it in the nib.

Comment: oh, ok. You could still add the UIImageView to the nib and then show the actual image programmatically by setting the 'image' property, but I guess the problem is solved now anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to keep putting imageViews in your cell, you have to do all the customization inside the `if(cell==nil)` block, otherwise it will add one every time a cell recycles.  When using cell recycling you always want to keep anything that is consistent for all of your cells in that block so that they only get added once.

Ex:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        //Add custom objects to the cell in here!
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]];

        imageView.center = CGPointMake(310, 48);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If each cell should need a different image, you can try something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    static const int ImageViewTag = 1234; //any integer constant

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIImageView *imageView;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        //Add custom objects to the cell in here!
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, imgWidth, imgHeight)];

        imageView.center = CGPointMake(310, 48);
        imageView.tag = ImageViewTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    else
    {
        imageView = [cell viewWithTag:ImageViewTag];
    }
    imageView.image = yourUIImageForThisCell;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: And as filipe pointed out in a comment above, it's even easier if you just add the UIImageView to the nib in the first place - then all you have to do is set the UIImageView's image property to the UIImage you want. I've used this method so often I have it in an abstract class which most of my table view controllers are based on.